# pandas.read_html can I specify format for parse_dates?

Tags: python, pandas

`pandas.read_csv` allows an argument `date_parser` but `pandas.read_html` doesn't.

How can I use `pandas.read_html` with a specific parser -- especially when parsing unusual formats?

Comment: Are you sure? sometimes these things accept `kwargs`, just try it

Comment: yes: `read_html() got an unexpected keyword argument 'date_parser'`

Comment: Shame, no reason why not IMO worth an improvement request on [github](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues)